# Cannot clear app data

Tags: applications, samsung, settings, sd-card, 8.0-oreo

### Specs

- Samsung Galaxy S8
- Android 8.0 Oreo
- App based on [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService) Google sample that works fine on other Galaxy S8 phones

### Question

On trying to start from scratch on my app installed by APK file, I am unable to remove the app data.

- Hitting the "Clear Data" button in app settings
- Running `adb shell pm clear com.myappsname`
- And uninstalling/reinstalling

Always leaves 16.38 kB in the Data category of the apps storage.

All I can figure is that this is what is causing the app to misbehave on this particular phone, since when installed on other S8's it works fine. Looking at logcat, I can't really diagnose anything wrong with the apps operation other than the fact that it is not updating location.

How do I completely clear the app's data (the 16.38 kB left)?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: How bout manual deletion? Android>Data>[App Name] and delete all its files

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow The app's folder is not there. That is cleared on clearing app data, yet settings still shows data that isn't cleared. I figured out that the problem with my app and this phone was not related to the extra data, yet I'm still curious as to why the app data can't be completely cleared. And this extra data can be reproduced on other phones with the app.

Comment: If that's the case, then the app might have written the unknown file in the root/data folder

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow How does the app even write to the root folder if the device isn't rooted?

Comment: It does at times, all applications has some traces in the root folder. If you have been rooted before, you can see that some apps has its data or cache files inside the root folder.

Comment: I am facing this same issue. It's terrible. I can't simulate an install from strach, because the data is always there and I can't wipe the data. Even tried restarting the device, but with no luck.